# Google APIs Explorer not allowing access to Cloud Endpoints V2 methods

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am attempting to migrate a Java AppEngine from Cloud Endpoints to Cloud Endpoints Framework. Ie v1 to v2.

Migration goes fine, the endpoints are all accessible on the new instance.
And discovery shows all the methods https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis

But when I use https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer for my appengine domain, while I can still see the API methods, when I drill down on them I can no longer provide params and execute them.

Looking at the AppEngine log I am seeing the following ClassCastException

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.api.server.spi.config.AnnotationBoolean cannot be cast to com.google.api.server.spi.config.AnnotationBoolean
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:145)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:559)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:519)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:489)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Which seems to match up to the attempts to drill down on the methods in API Explorer. These errors don't occur with v1 of Cloud Endpoints.

The ClassCast implies that the AnnotationBoolen has been loaded into 2 different classloaders. I'm not playing with classloaders myself, so I presume this is something new for Endpoints v2. What do I change to avoid the ClassCast?

Does API Explorer not fully support Cloud Endpoints Framework?

Is there some extra step I need to take to enable method execution via API Explorer for Cloud Endpoints Framework?

Comment: This error looks unrelated to API Explorer. Are you using the quickstart or your own app?

Comment: My own app. I don't really need to migrate an old quick-start. I suspect that the migration instructions are not correct, that it is not an API Explorer issue

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: That's all that is available in the AppEngine logs (and from api explorer). It doesn't pass through any of my code, so I can't see how to inject any exception handling to dig deeper.

Comment: Willian, I am running in the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: @Julien thanks for reminding me. I meant to update this with the solution.See below.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Cloud EndPoints Frameworks migration guide these maven goals are no longer supported.

```
                      <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                      <goal>endpoints_get_client_lib</goal>
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/endpoints/migrating

It **also** looks like you need to

1. Add Cloud Endpoints API management to your app.
   See https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management
2. Generate an API configuration file and deploy it PRIOR to deploying the app.
   See https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/test-deploy
3. Generate client libs using ...

See https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java

Step 1 means adding something like the following to your web.xml:

```
<!--
    EndPoints management API. See https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management
-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<!--
    EndPoints management API. See https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management
-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
        <param-value>your-appengine-projectid</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
        <param-value>your-appengine-project-url.appspot.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ClassCastException` that you experienced is due to loading the old `SystemServiceServlet` instead of the new `EndpointsServlet`.  Configure your `web.xml` to replace

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

with

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```